# Can Qt-box-editor be used for tesseract 4.0?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract 4.0 for character recognition. In many blogs, it is written that Qt-box-editor can be used with tesseract 3.x. My question is:- Can Qt-box-editor be used with tesseract 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, *Qt-box-editor(1.11)* can support the Legacy Tesseract OCR's training *.box* file. and also can support the *.box* file generated by `text2image`.

However, it doesn't support the *.box* file generated with `lstmbox` or `wordstrbox` config. more information you can find in [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2357)